# php separate html into if statement wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

a little question about why something that should work in theory doesn't work for me.

Target. Separate the html code from the if loop

example:

```
if ($condition){
    echo "no";
}
else{?>
     <p>yes</p>
<?php}?>
```

but if copy and paste this in my custom theme in wordpress:

```
<?php
$AMC_metakey_video = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metakey_AMC_video', true );

    if ($AMC_metakey_video === ''){
        echo "Gratis";
    }
    else{?>
        <p>no</p>
    <?php}?>
```

i have blank result... i don't know, why?

Comment: insert a space right after the opening tag in your last line: change `<?php}?>` to `<?php }?>` - the opening tag just likes its space :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php $AMC_metakey_video = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metakey_AMC_video', true ); ?>

   <?php if(empty($AMC_metakey_video)): ?>
        <p>Gratis</p> or any HTML

   <?php else: ?>
        else HTML
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @user12067856 Better way to open new question, otherwise this thread will be to long and answers will be not accurate.

Comment: ok, perfect i delete the second part, and i delete this comment after 5 minutes for to give other users a clear question and a clear answer, thanks for your contribution